# Is there a way to use CSS to show/hide elements that are not siblings?

Tags: css

I have some radio options that have the classes I would like to show/hide. I have some divs that have those classes.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" class="one radioselect" value="one" id="one" name="opts" /> <label for="one" class="select radlabel">one</label>
<input type="radio" class="two radioselect" value="two" id="two" name="opts" /> <label for="two" class="select radlabel">two</label>

<div class="one">abc</div>
<div class="two">def</div>
```

CSS:

```
input.one:checked ~ a.one { display:inline; }
input.two:checked ~ a.two { display:inline; }

input.one:checked ~ a:not(.one) { display:none; }
input.two:checked ~ a:not(.two) { display:none; }
```

Now my markup must be this:

```
<div class="row">
<input type="radio" class="one radioselect" value="one" id="one" name="opts" /> <label for="one" class="select radlabel">one</label>
<input type="radio" class="two radioselect" value="two" id="two" name="opts" /> <label for="two" class="select radlabel">two</label>
</div>

<div class="one">abc</div>
<div class="two">def</div>
```

The new markup means that the inputs are no longer siblings to the divs and the CSS is no longer applied (as I understand it). 
I have tried all the combinations of selectors I can think of and maybe this just isn't possible with plain CSS. My goal was to avoid javascript where CSS would work. I am willing to look into SASS/LESS if this is a solution.

Comment: Not possible with the HTML you have specified. Are the radio buttons visible ? If not you could put them outside the `.row` (*as before*) and leave the `label` elements only in the `.row`.

Comment: That might work. I will get back to you but I can't select your comment as an answer if it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment by Gaby I adjusted the markup to look more like this:
HTML

```
<div class="row">
<label for="one" class="select radlabel">one</label>
<label for="two" class="select radlabel">two</label>
</div>
<input type="radio" class="one radioselect hide" value="one" id="one" name="opts" /> 
<input type="radio" class="two radioselect hide" value="two" id="two" name="opts" /> 
<div class="one">abc</div>
<div class="two">def</div>
```

CSS

```
input.one:checked ~ a.one { display:inline; }
input.two:checked ~ a.two { display:inline; }

input.one:checked ~ a:not(.one) { display:none; }
input.two:checked ~ a:not(.two) { display:none; }
```

The filtering does work but the radio options are not visible and the best I have been able to do for visual cues has been giving the label styling when :active.

It is a fit enough for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have rearranged your HTML to get the functionality you were after. First I renamed the classes on your divs that were to show and hid them.

```
.three { display:none; }
.four { display:none; }
```

Next you create the logic when a radio button is checked you display a div.

```
input.one[type=radio]:checked ~ .three { display:block; }
input.two[type=radio]:checked ~ .four { display:block; }
```

Now once compiled into one it should look like below:

```css
.three { display:none;color:#ff0000;}
.four { display:none;color:#FF8C00;}

input.one[type=radio]:checked ~ .three { display:block; }
input.two[type=radio]:checked ~ .four { display:block; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
<input type="radio" class="one radioselect" value="one" id="one" name="opts" /> <label for="one" class="select radlabel">Radio one</label>
<input type="radio" class="two radioselect" value="two" id="two" name="opts" /> <label for="two" class="select radlabel">Radio two</label>

<div class="three">Radio one DIV</div>
<div class="four">Radio two DIV</div>


</div>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This is pretty much what it was before but now the inputs are in a separate div that is collapsible and the other divs are what I want to filter but not be hidden by collapsing the radio options..